# Geometric example of a one object cover which does not satisfy the sheaf condition?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, schemes

For topological spaces, a one object cover automatically satisfies the sheaf axiom because open inclusions are injective, which is equivalent to the projections of the kernel pair (= self intersection) being equal as arrows.

In the general context of sheaves on sites, however, it may happen that an arrow $U_i\rightarrow U$ in a coverage may not be a mono, in which case the projections from $U_i\times _U U_i$ will differ, and the sheaf condition will not be trivially satisfied.

Is there a geometric example of such a failure? Maybe something from the category of topological spaces with the étale topology? Can open embeddings of schemes fail to be monic?

Comment: An open embedding of schemes is always injective, but an étale morphism certainly is not in general.

Comment: Arrow is asking whether open embeddings  are monic, not whether they are injective.

Comment: What about the double cover of the circle and the constant presheaf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An open embedding  of schemes  (called open immersion in algebraic geometry, alas!)  is always monic, which answers your last question.
Of course a monomorphism of schemes needn't be an open immersion: a closed immersions is always a monomorphisms but extremely rarely an open immersion!.
(Actually the closed immersions are exactly the **proper** monomorphisms  : EGA IV, 18.12.6.)